# Unable to change the managed metadata fields for my Files and Folders inside my remote event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, remote-event-receiver

I have the following code inside my RER:-

```
foreach (ListItem currentFilingSystemItem in collListItem)
    {
Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
context.Load(folder);
context.ExecuteQuery(); 
folder.MoveTo(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
folder.Update();

context.Load(folder);
context.Load(folder.Files);
context.Load(folder.Folders);
FileCollection files = folder.Files;
FolderCollection folders = folder.Folders;
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (File f in files)
  {
     ListItem item = f.ListItemAllFields;
     context.Load(item);
     context.ExecuteQuery();
     item["DealStage"] = currentFilingSystemItem["DealStage"];
     item.Update();
     context.ExecuteQuery();

  }
foreach (Folder fo in folders)
  {

      ListItem item = fo.ListItemAllFields;
      context.Load(item);
      context.ExecuteQuery();
      item["DealStage"] = currentFilingSystemItem["DealStage"];
      item.Update();
      context.ExecuteQuery();

  }
```

where i am trying to change a managed metadata column named "DealStage" using this `item["DealStage"] = currentFilingSystemItem["DealStage"];` for both File and Folders, but my above code will not raise any exception, but the `DealStage` will not get update! can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Comment: Does`DealStage` allow multiple Term selections, or just single value?

Comment: @willman it is a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in response to your other posted question, you should use [`TaxonomyFieldValue`][1] (for single-value managed metadata columns) and [`TaxonomyFieldValueCollection`][2] (for multi-value managed metadata columns).  In most cases, setting a taxonomy field to a raw guid will **not** update the value correctly.  Also note the use of the `SetFieldValueByValue` method on the actual Field object, rather than simply setting the field equal to a value.  Taxonomy fields are considerably more difficult to code updates for than scalar value fields are.

Give this a try:

```
foreach (ListItem currentFilingSystemItem in collListItem)
{
    Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
    context.Load(folder);
    context.ExecuteQuery(); 
    folder.MoveTo(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
    folder.Update();

    context.Load(folder);
    FileCollection files = folder.Files;
    FolderCollection folders = folder.Folders;

    context.Load(files, fs => fs.Include(f => f.ListItemAllFields));
    context.Load(folders, fs => fs.Include(f => f.ListItemAllFields));
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    var dealStageField = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("DealStage");
    context.Load(dealStageField);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    var dealStageTaxField = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);
    var dealStageTermValue = currentFilingSystemItem["DealStage"] as TaxonomyFieldValue;

    foreach (File f in files)
    {
        ListItem item = f.ListItemAllFields;
        dealStageTaxField.SetFieldValueByValue(item, dealStageTermValue);
        item.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    foreach (Folder fo in folders)
    {
        ListItem item = fo.ListItemAllFields;
        dealStageTaxField.SetFieldValueByValue(item, dealStageTermValue);
        item.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: your code worked for me, thanks a lot for the help.. but do you know why my code did not work, although on paper it should..

Comment: The two big difficulties with setting a Taxonomy value, are making sure your value is stored in a TaxonomyFieldValue object -- which in your case should already be true since you are copying it from an existing item's field; but the second issue is you can't just set `item["mytaxfield"] =` the value even if it is already a TaxonomyFieldValue , you have to use the `Field.SetFieldValueByValue(listItemTeBeUpdated, taxonomyFieldValueToSave)`.  It was likely this second issue that was catching you.